# How can I check and store user id in Angular and localstorage

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app where user can create account and login with his credentials. Everything works fine except I get an error message in console before user is loged in and there is no localStorage values yet, so I need to check if localStorage alreafy exists before calling getUser function from navbar component -

```
Cannot read property 'id' of null
at AuthenticationService.getUser (auth.service.ts:55)
at SafeSubscriber._next (navbar.component.ts:31)
```

Here is relevant code from auth.service.ts:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  //public id = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    //this.id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id;
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth/`, { email, password })
      .pipe(map(user => {
        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
        console.log("TCL: AuthenticationService -> login -> user", user)
        return user;
      }));
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }

  getUser() {
    //if (this.id != null) {
    let id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id;
    return this.http.get<any>((`${environment.apiUrl}/api/user/${id}`));
    //}
  }
}
```

I've tried to add commented lanes of code but it didn't help. What an I doing wrong and how may I get rid of that console error? Also I would like to ask how can i store user id globally in auth.service and not invoke it like this `let id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id;` in each service function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add the output of localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));

Comment: Could you show output of this console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));?

Comment: I think id in your JSON object is having null value. Can you provide your JSON object?

Comment: There is no output since user is not logged in yet so there can't be anything in localStorage. My goal is to check if user is logged in (there is user's value in localStorage) and only then invoke getUser function

Comment: What are you getting as response? If you are not getting response, then you are not storing anything in localStorage. And if you are not setting localStorage, you can't access that variable. May be, you are accessing localStorage even before it is assigned. That is why you are getting cannot read property of id null. Can you also tell from where you are calling getUser() ?

Comment: Yes, I think I'm trying to access localStorage before it's invoked, so that's why I'm asking - how can I check if there is any value in localStorage before I will try to get id from there, I've tried something like this `if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id)` but it didn't help. I'm calling getUser function from navbar component via auth.service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that, you want to request the server for login only if user is not logged in. Then, what you have to do is check if the currentUser is existing.

```
const user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
// if user is null
if(!user) {
  // go for login
} else {
  // redirect to home through navigateByURL()
}
```

Don't forget to remove currentuser from localStorage after log out:

```
localStorage.removeItem('currentUser'); // after logout
```

Don't check for currentUser.id. Because, currentUser is null and you are asking to get id from null.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've forgotten that id cannot exist right there...